# Is there a direct URL for viewing today's date on the Google Maps Timeline?

Tags: google-maps, location-history

I often use the Google Maps Timeline feature to review places I've been to on a particular day. While I can bookmark the main Timeline URL (https://timeline.google.com/maps/timeline), it defaults to a general overview rather than the current day.

Is there a direct URL that can take me to the Timeline for today's date?

Answer (score 2):

Found it: [https://timeline.google.com/maps/timeline**/today**](https://timeline.google.com/maps/timeline/today)

This URL directly opens the Google Maps Timeline for the current day, eliminating the need to click the "Today" button.